# Selected value of dropdown persists even after reloading options

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I will describe a bug I am having trouble fixing.

I am using this [select/dropdown](https://react-select.com).

Assume the dropdown is already populated and option1 was already selected. 
User uses another control, hence handlePopulate() is called. In the dropdown 'option1' label is still visible.

Scenario 1:   When the insert button is pressed, we see that the old 'value' is inserted. Bad!

Scenario 2: User clicks on the dropdown and selects another option. When the insert button is pressed, we see that the new 'value' is used. Good.

Scenario 3: User clicks the dropdown but does not select a new option. Closes the menu by clicking on dropdown again. old 'value' is used. Bad!

Scenario 4: User clicks the dropdown. And selects the option 1 again. Now the new 'value' is used.

So, how can I fix this?

```
// React Hooks based state
const [insertFields, setInsertFields] = React.useState<FieldData[]>([]);
const [selectedInsertField, setSelectedInsertField] = React.useState<FieldData | undefined>();


// skip

const handlePopulate= async () => {
  // skip
  setInsertFields(newFields)
}

//React element Hierarcy
<Select
  options={insertFields}
  defaultValue={insertFields[0]}
  onChange={handleFieldSelection} // calls setSelectedInsertField(newValue)
/>
// When clicked this butten uses selectedInsertField
<Button .../>Insert</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `defaultValue`, use `value` prop and use useState to provide the default value. Example provided below.

```
// React Hooks based state
const [insertFields, setInsertFields] = React.useState<FieldData[]>([]);

// Provide default value here
const [selectedInsertField, setSelectedInsertField] = React.useState<FieldData | undefined>(insertFields[0]);


// skip

const handlePopulate= async () => {
  // skip
  setInsertFields(newFields)
}





//React element Hierarcy
// Change defaultValue to value
<Select
  options={insertFields}
  value={selectedInsertField}
  onChange={handleFieldSelection} // calls setSelectedInsertField(newValue)
/>
// When clicked this butten uses selectedInsertField
<Button .../>Insert</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I also needed to call setSelectedInsertField(newFields[0]) in the handlePopulate() to make it work.